# Comparison between Google Cloud Endpoints vs Cloud Datastore api Service

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

i wanted to access appengine datastore of one application in another internal appengine application, i have used endpoints a lot, now i tried cloud datastore api using Google protobuf client library.

my question is ,

**which service will be high performing, ignore the fact that endpoints acts as an api and consider in terms of datastore access only) ?**

any better suggestion is also helpful!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They are currently very similar. The main difference is that endpoints encodes using JSON and GCD uses a binary format (protobufs). This is only an issue if you send around entities with large blobs (in which case GCD is more efficient). On the other hand, Endpoints lets you write custom code to validate requests, post process results, etc.

Things might change in the future, however, as GCD will likely become faster and cheaper.

Comment: thank you alfred, though currently GCD Api seems to be very limited in  functionality it looks very promising.

Comment: what functionality would you like to see incorporated?

Comment: the current impl is very abstract and hard to use, it would be better if the api was less abstract or native impl like JDO or objectify

Comment: Note that GCD also support JSON for other languages (Node.js, Ruby, Dart)

Comment: I would prefer endpoints. You could reuse any code you already wrote for validation and consistency checks etc.